# ParameterExpression of type 'Program+StringEventArgs' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'System.EventArgs'

Tags: c#, type-conversion, delegates, expression, func

I am trying to transform a `MethodInfo` into a `Func<T, TResult>` using reflection. My code seems to work so far in certain cases, but I'm not able to create a `Func` with a parameter type that is derived from another one. I'm missing something and I unfortunately do not know how to proceed from there. I guess some kind of `Expression.Convert()` would be in order, if so, where and how?

Here is a short program that tests what I am trying to achieve. It can be copy-pasted at `https://dotnetfiddle.net/` and should be compiling.

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var myObject = new MyClass();
        var methodInfo = myObject.GetType().GetMethod("HelloThere");
        var parameterType = methodInfo.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;
        var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(parameterType);
        var callExpression = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(myObject), methodInfo, parameterExpression);
        var compiledFunction = Expression.Lambda<Func<EventArgs, string>>(callExpression, parameterExpression).Compile();
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public string HelloThere(StringEventArgs args)
        {
            return "General Kenobi";
        }
    }

    public class StringEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public StringEventArgs(string aString)
        {
            Value = aString;
        }

        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

However, the following error is being thrown at runtime:

```
Run-time exception (line 13): ParameterExpression of type 'Program+StringEventArgs' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'System.EventArgs'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

The first is that you've declared a `ParameterExpression` with a type of `StringEventArgs`, and then you're trying to use that as the parameter in a `Func<EventArgs, string>`. That won't work: you need to declare your `ParameterExpression` with a type of `EventArgs`.

The second problem is that you're basically trying to construct this C# code using expressions:

```
public string GeneratedMethod(EventArgs e)
{
    return myClass.HelloThere(e);
}
```

That won't compile, because you're taking an object of type `EventArgs` and trying to pass it to a method which accepts a `StringEventArgs`.

In C#, you can add a cast, which will fail at runtime if you don't actually pass a `StringEventArgs`:

```
public string GeneratedMethod(EventArgs e)
{
    return myClass.HelloThere((StringEventArgs)e);
}
```

The equivalent expression is `Expression.Convert`.

Put that all together, and you get:

```
var myObject = new MyClass();
var methodInfo = myObject.GetType().GetMethod("HelloThere");
var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(EventArgs));
var parameterType = methodInfo.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;
var methodParameter = Expression.Convert(parameterExpression, parameterType);
var callExpression = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(myObject), methodInfo, methodParameter);
var compiledFunction = Expression.Lambda<Func<EventArgs, string>>(callExpression, parameterExpression).Compile();
```

This of course will fail at runtime with an `InvalidCastException` if you pass something which isn't a `StringEventArgs`, even though the signature of `compiledFunction` says that it can accept any type of `EventArgs`.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling the Lambda method with

```
var compiledFunction = Expression.Lambda<Func<EventArgs, string>>(callExpression, parameterExpression).Compile();
```

you are specifying that the type of the delegate is Func<EventArgs,string>. However that would only be the case if your parameter type were EventArgs and the return type from HelloThere were string. From the error message that you are receiving it would appear that that these are not the actual types; for example the error refers to a type StringEventArgs that is nested in the Program type.

Also if you knew that the parameter type is EventArgs then there would be little point to obtaining the parameterType value dynamically.

What you could try would be using a different overload of Expression.Lambda. Leave out the type parameter and just call

```
 var compiledFunction = Expression.Lambda(callExpression, new ParameterExpression[] { parameterExpression }).Compile();
```

This should construct the lambda type dynamically from the types of the parameter expressions and the type of the call expression.

Caveat: I haven't actually tried it.